# Posting a photo to the wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photos

Is it possible to post a photo to the wall (and not to the album created for the application)?
I thought about iterating through all of the user's albums and posting to the one called "Wall Photos", but wonder if there is a more elegant way?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to post just any image, which will open an external URL for the image, or do you want the image to display like it does in a Facebook album? Because the first option is possible, but the second one is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the FB.ui method from the Javascript SDK. If you provide the URL for the image as the `link` and `picture` parameter. This will create a wall post for the active user that has an image, a title, caption, description, etc. And the image and title will link to whatever URL you have provided.

```
FB.ui({
   method: 'feed',
   name: 'Name Goes Here',
   link: 'link to the image',
   picture: 'link to the image',
   caption: 'caption goes here',
   description: 'description goes here',
   properties: ''
   }, 
   function(response) {
       //You can check the response variable to see if the post has been created
   }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Albums have a type that you can see when requesting /albums in the Graph API, so instead of checking for name you can check for this.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually used the method listed here https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526/ .
First uploaded the photo and then linked to it using object_attachment.